# do not duplicate posts in 1 loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, duplicates

i want to display posts for each term as term, but am not able to stop duplicate posts

my wordpress structure is :

Parent Category 1

- Sub Category 1
- Title
- Title
- Sub Category 2
- Title
- Title
  Parent Category 2
- Sub Category 1
- Title
- Title
- Sub Category 2
- Title
- Title
  Category 3
- Title
- Title

N.B.: sometimes posts are associated with 2 category, how to remove duplicates ?

http://pastebin.com/109ni3BK

Comment: Instead of looping terms why not pass it as arguments ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters.  Should be simpler.

Comment: An another example how to pass multiple taxonomy https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: but i need to display "for each term as term"

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you mean by "term as term". You don't want to display posts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you're just not populating `$do_not_duplicate` at the right spot, and you're not checking it to see if the current post is already in it.

Change your `if` block to something like this (untested, but it should give you the idea):

```
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        if (in_array($post_id, $do_not_duplicate)) {
            continue; // We've already seen this post ID, so skip the rest of the loop
        }

        $do_not_duplicate[] = $post_id;
        ?>
                <tr>
                                <td><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/contactfullname.php'); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_position', true); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo p2p_get_meta( get_post()->p2p_id, 'table', true ); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo ' ' .$term->name;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo p2p_get_meta( get_post()->p2p_id, 'confirmation', true ); ?></td>
                </tr>
        <?php
    endwhile;
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, just saw you're using `$do_not_duplicate` in your `$args`.  In which case, it may be enough to move the code for setting it into the `while` loop:

```
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

Comment: No problem; happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_filter('post_link', 'track_displayed_posts');
add_action('pre_get_posts','remove_already_displayed_posts');

$displayed_posts = [];

function track_displayed_posts($url) {
  global $displayed_posts;
  $displayed_posts[] = get_the_ID();
  return $url; // don't mess with the url
}

function remove_already_displayed_posts($query) {
 global $displayed_posts;
 $query->set('post__not_in', $displayed_posts);
}
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @user1062954.